# Increment by 1 in string replacement

Tags: r, function, loops, increment

I have a line of code that needs to be run 12 times with a string replacement each time.

```
unique1 <- unique(master[c("Country_University_1", "City_University_1", "Latitude_city_1", "Longitude_city_1")])
```

By incrementing the numbers at the end of each column name by one, this would produce 12 separate dataframes which I would then bind together with `rbind`

My objective is to write a function that takes the last character of the column name  *and*  the object name and increments by 1 like `x <- x + 1` and stops at 12.  I have been hopelessly trying to write a function that looks something like

```
x <- c("Country_University_1", "City_University_1", "Latitude_city_1", "Longitude_city_1")
for (i in 1:12){
  gsub("i", nchar(x[1:4]-1 ) x[1:4])
  print(x)
}
```

but I am still unfamiliar with R syntax. Any advice would be appreciated

Written out fully, the function would perform the following:

```
unique1 <- unique(master[c("Country_University_1", "City_University_1", "Latitude_city_1", "Longitude_city_1")])
unique2 <- unique(master[c("Country_University_2", "City_University_2", "Latitude_city_2", "Longitude_city_2")])
unique3 <- unique(master[c("Country_University_3", "City_University_3", "Latitude_city_3", "Longitude_city_3")])
unique4 <- unique(master[c("Country_University_4", "City_University_4", "Latitude_city_4", "Longitude_city_4")])
unique5 <- unique(master[c("Country_University_5", "City_University_5", "Latitude_city_5", "Longitude_city_5")])
unique6 <- unique(master[c("Country_University_6", "City_University_6", "Latitude_city_6", "Longitude_city_6")])
unique7 <- unique(master[c("Country_University_7", "City_University_7", "Latitude_city_7", "Longitude_city_7")])
unique8 <- unique(master[c("Country_University_8", "City_University_8", "Latitude_city_8", "Longitude_city_8")])
unique9 <- unique(master[c("Country_University_9", "City_University_9", "Latitude_city_9", "Longitude_city_9")])
unique10 <- unique(master[c("Country_University_10", "City_University_10", "Latitude_city_10", "Longitude_city_10")])
unique11 <- unique(master[c("Country_University_11", "City_University_11", "Latitude_city_11", "Longitude_city_11")])
unique12 <- unique(master[c("Country_University_12", "City_University_12", "Latitude_city_12", "Longitude_city_12")])

output <- rbind(unique1, unique2, unique3, unique4, unique5, unique6, unique7, unique8, unique9, unique10, unique11, unique12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redone to match request.

```
Base = c("Country_University_", "City_University_", "Latitude_city_", "Longitude_city_")
output = rep(NULL,4)
for(i in 1:12) {
    ColNames = sapply(Base, function(s) { paste(s, i, sep="") })
    output=rbind(output, unique(master[ColNames]))
}
```

This code is not tested because we don't have master, but output should be what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question to be a little more precise.  I've written out the full code manually - I am just wondering how I can automate this in the future.  How would you include the `rbind` element into your solution?

Comment: What does `master` do?

Comment: `master` is the name of the dataframe containing all 48 of those columns

Comment: OK,   we can't test the solution without having `master` to work with, but I think that I know what you need.

Comment: All new solution posted

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some regex with `sub`. Looks like you want to replace the digit at the end of string with an increasing number, you can check on this, where in the pattern `$` matches the end of string and thus `\\d+$` matches digit at the end of string:

```
for (i in 1:2) { print(sub("\\d+$", i, x)) }

#[1] "Country_University_1" "City_University_1"    "Latitude_city_1"     
#[4] "Longitude_city_1"    
#[1] "Country_University_2" "City_University_2"    "Latitude_city_2"     
#[4] "Longitude_city_2"
```

---

According to your update, you probably want something like this instead:

```
# get the number at the end of column names
number = sub(".*_(\\d+)$", "\\1", names(master))

# split the data frame by the number, rename each sub data frame and bind them together
do.call(rbind, lapply(split.default(master, number), 
                      function(sdf) setNames(sdf, sub("_\\d+$", "", names(sdf)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this easily using `melt` from `data.table` which can take multiple `measure` `patterns`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(master), measure = patterns("^Country", "^City", "^Latitude", "^Longitude"), 
  value.name = c("Country_University", "City_University", "Latitude_city", "Longitude_city")
         ][, variable := NULL][]
```